# How to make my non-max suppression implementation faster?

Tags: python, algorithm, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have implemented [NMS](https://towardsdatascience.com/non-maximum-suppression-nms-93ce178e177c) as below and encountered a run-time issue. The worst case time complexity of this algorithm is `O(N^2)`.

Is there a way to do it faster? I have data frames with `100,000-200,000` calls

```
def NMS(df,K=0.6):
    all_boxes = []
    for _,row in df.iterrows():
        all_boxes.append(Box(row.x1,row.y1,row.x2,row.y2,row.probability))
    all_boxes.sort(key=lambda x: x.prob, reverse=True)
    N=len(all_boxes)
    B=[i for i in range(N)]
    D=[]
    while len(B)>0:
        highest_box_idx = B.pop(0)
        highest_box     = all_boxes[highest_box_idx]
        D.append(highest_box_idx)
        for b_idx in B:
            other_box = all_boxes[b_idx]
            if highest_box.IoU(other_box)>K:
                B.remove(b_idx)
    return df.iloc[D,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Malisiewicz et al. method](http://www.computervisionblog.com/2011/08/blazing-fast-nmsm-from-exemplar-svm.html).

I read about as part of the quest to [recognize Zombies](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/)

Let us know how it worked out for you!

Computer Vision rocks!  Keep notes on it.